# Why might my SELECT control change selectedIndex not change sometimes?

Tags: c#, html

Background: I am running a process nightly that reads a database and then writes the results into another system. The target system does not have an interface other than HTML Web Service with a UI. I originally set up this system a few years ago and it was really reliable when running in IE 9. However, the host that I have to run this process on has changed from Windows 2008 R2 to 2012 R2 and the version of IE has changed to IE 11 and it mostly works, but in infuriatingly SOME cases, it does NOT work.

I am manipulating a web page with a dropdown SELECT with either "Off" (value=0) or "On" (value=1) and the name of the dropdown is variable, as there are multiple identical dropdowns, which I find and then set individually.

I have written some code to find the SELECT and to set the value, but in SOME cases, it works like a charm and in others, it just does NOT set the value, even though I have stepped through the code and watched IE with the page, which does not set the value. The code is here:

```
bool bDone = false;
mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection objEventCollection = (mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection)objDocument.getElementsByTagName("select");
for (int i = 0; i < objEventCollection.length; i++)
{
    mshtml.IHTMLElement objElement = (mshtml.IHTMLElement)objEventCollection.item(i, 0);
    if (objElement.getAttribute("name").EndsWith("NewEvent"))
    {
        objElement.click();
        mshtml.HTMLSelectElement objEvent = (mshtml.HTMLSelectElement)objElement;
        switch (sEventType)
        {
            case "Off":
                objEvent.selectedIndex = 0; // This SOMETIMES works and SOMETIMES will error out!
                bDone = true;
                break;
            case "On":
                objEvent.selectedIndex = 1; // This SOMETIMES works and SOMETIMES will error out!
                bDone = true;
                break;
        }
    }
    if (bDone)
    {
        break;
    }
}
bOK = bDone;
```

The relevant page code looks like this:

```
<td valign="middle" align="center"><input class="data" type="hidden" name="No1EventString" value="0"><input class="data" type="hidden" name="No1OriginalEvent" value="0"><select class="data" name="No1NewEvent">
<option value="0" selected="">Off</option>
<option value="1">On</option>
</select></td>
```

I don't know why SOMETIMES, the value of the NewEvent dropdown is changing, but not every time.

When I run this in debug, it runs through quite happily, but then, sometimes, I get the following error:

[image]

Does anyone know of a more reliable method for setting this, if I can't fix it?

Alternatively, are there any workarounds, such as setting the focus to the SELECT and then pressing the down button (but I don't know how to do this)?

Comment: Umm, where is your code running? In a browser? A VB script? Something else?

Comment: The code is running in a Win32 Application.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got to learn something during my lunch:

It seems that IE 11 SOMETIMES rejects the IHTMLElement.selectedIndex = x lines, but when I changed the lines to IHTMLElement.value = x instead, it was reliable!

When did that change?